# Scala: Generic function set -> mutable map

Tags: scala

I have an issue with the scala type hinting w.r.t generic types. I would like to write a function as follows:

```
def set2mutable_map[A,B](set:Set[A],default:B):collection.mutable.Map[A,B] = {
    collection.mutable.Map[A,B](
       set.map(s => (s,default):_*)
    )
}
```

However, this fails with the following error message:

```
type mismatch;
found : scala.collection.immutable.Set[Nothing]
required: (A,B)
    set.map(s => (s,default):_*)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to use `: _*` ascription on tuple `(s, default)`. It would work only on sequence:

```
def set2mutable_map[A,B](set:Set[A],default:B):collection.mutable.Map[A,B] = {
    collection.mutable.Map[A,B](
      set.map(s => (s,default)).toSeq:_*
    )
}
```